# Show that given path is rectifiable

Tags: complex-analysis

I was solving some problems from Conway's complex analysis and stuck on following problem

let $\gamma(t) = \text{exp}(\dfrac{-1+i}{t})  0 < t \le 1$ and $\gamma(0) = 0$, I need to show that is path is rectifiable and also sketch the trace of $\gamma$

Now,

$\gamma'(t) = \dfrac{1-i}{t^2} \text{exp}(\dfrac{-1+i}{t})$,  $0 < t \le 1$

also $\gamma'(0)  = \displaystyle\lim_{h \to 0} \dfrac{\text{exp}(\dfrac{-1+i}{h})}{h}$, which diverges to $\infty$ ,

The length is given by  :

$\displaystyle \int_0^{1} \left|\gamma'(t)\right|dt$

using this formula, I get

$\displaystyle \lim_{t \to 0+} \int_{t}^{1} \dfrac{\sqrt{2}}{t^2} \text{exp(-1/t)}$

I don't see how to show this integral is finite.

Comment: Why the downvote? Is something wrong with my question?

Comment: It's not quite clear where you're having difficulty.  Do you not know the formula for arc length?  Can you not evaluate the integral?  Please show exactly how far you have gotten and what in particular is troubling you.

Comment: @saulspatz I have added some details in the question, my main issue is proving that integral converges.

Comment: You haven't computed the modulus correctly.

Comment: Do not forget the exponential as its absolute value is the exponential of the real part and that will be very fast decaying at zero

Comment: Substitute $u = t^{-1}, du = -t^{-2}$ to evaluate your integral.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**: It is possible to show that the inequality
$$
\frac{\sqrt{2}}{t^2}e^{-\frac{1}{t}} \leq 2t
$$
holds for $0 < t \leq 1$. Then it follows that your integral is finite.